# Store the NULL value for a PictureEdit.Image

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a PictureEdit in my form and a button to save this PictureEdit.Image to an SQL DataBase.

I wrote this code :

```
Byte[] imgData = new ImageConverter().ConvertTo(auteurPhoto.Image, typeof(Byte[])) as Byte[];
                        row[11] = imgData == null ?
                           DBNull.Value :
                           imgData as Object;
```

But the problem when there is no picture in the PictureEdit.Image it store the value 0x on the Image's column and I want to store the NULL value !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
row[11] = imgData == null || imgData.Length == 0 ? DBNull.Value : imgData as Object;
```

instead.